# Where to declare the wp_rewrite codes? wp_rewrite issues

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, wordpress

I have a question regarding wp_rewrite, It doesn't display correctly,

I need to make this url 
`eduedu/wp-content/plugins/workwork/admin/templates/tcpdf/samp/flash.php`

to

`eduedu/generator`

It works when using `.htaccess`, the problem is, that It doesnt work when place inside the plugin folder, the htaccess must be place in the root folder of wordpress. So I thought of using `wp_rewrite`.

Here is my code, I added this on the page when in it will redirect to 
`eduedu/wp-content/plugins/workwork/admin/templates/tcpdf/samp/flash.php`
I'm not sure if its correct, any idea?

```
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'cs_rewrite_rules');   
add_filter('init', 'eduFlush');
function cs_rewrite_rules() { 
  global $wp_rewrite; 
  $new_non_wp_rules = array( 
    '^generator/?$'   => 'eduedu/wp-content/plugins/workwork/admin/templates/tcpdf/samp/flash.php', 
  ); 
  $wp_rewrite->non_wp_rules += $new_non_wp_rules; 
}  

function eduFlush(){
global $wp_rewrite;
  $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something along these lines would help:

```
function site_router() {

global $url_array;
    $url_array = explode("/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $route = $url_array[1];
    $template_dir = 'wp-content/plugins/workwork/admin/templates/tcpdf';
    switch($route) {
    case 'generator':
        load_template($template_dir.'/samp/flash.php');
        die();
        break;
    }
}

add_action( 'send_headers', 'site_router');
```

It gets the current URL array (domain.com/url_array[1]), then it gets where you want to get the file from.

The switch gets the url, so domain.com/generator, and then loads in the template from the file you call.

You may need to change the url_array[1] to [2] if wordpress is in a sub-folder (domain.com/wp_root)

Comment: I did tried your codes but still redirecting to  eduedu/wp-content/plugins/workwork/admin/templates/tcpdf/samp/flash.php